# How to call function when update state and after DOM full loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want when update state and after DOM full loaded, I will use js to update CSS. So now, I'm using `document ready function` in the method. Is there any writing style in Vuex? How can I write them in mounted?

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'wsInfo'
        ])
},
mounted () {
    ??????
},
method: {
        moveWs (from, to) {
            //update state
            this.wsInfo.workspaces.splice(to, 0, this.wsInfo.workspaces.splice(from, 1)[0])
            
             $(document).ready(function () {
                  // code run after update state and dom loaded
             })
        }
}
```

[image: full code here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a nextTick Function.
Also you can use it inside a method vuejs object.

You can read more about it here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  methods: {
    // ...
    example: function () {
      // modify data
      this.message = 'changed'
      // DOM is not updated yet
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        // DOM is now updated
        // `this` is bound to the current instance
        this.doSomethingElse()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: But, I'm using it inside method moveWorkspace, how can I split them into mounted

Comment: I've updated the code, you can use this.$nextTick inside a method as well. I guess it can help you.